# How to do a firebird SP, SELECT * FROM "TABLE"?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, select, firebird

I'm migrating from SQL Server to Firebird.

In SQL Server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Departments_GetAll
AS
    SELECT * FROM Departments
```

I try in Firebird

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DEPARTMENTS_DELETEALL
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM "Departments";
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

But that doesn't work.

It returns an error "SQL Code -104"

Comment: Advice: don't use quotes in identifiers unless you really understand what it does and why you do need it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A stored procedure needs return parameters and the `suspend` command in order to return multiple rows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DEPARTMENTS_GET_ALL
returns(id integer, name varchar(100))
AS 
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT id, name
  FROM "Departments"
  into :id, :name do
  BEGIN
    SUSPEND;
  END
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: If I have 'n' (10) the number of columns, then I should mention all those columns individually? Is there any alternate solution for this case?